# Vuforia app crashes upon camera init on iPhone 6

Tags: iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

So I have a Vuforia app running perfectly on many versions of Android.

I have ported the Unity project to a MAC running Unity & XCode.

App compiles and deploys correctly to an iPad Air2 and iPhone 6 both running iOS 10.

App on iPad works no problem.

App on iPhone 6 crashes as soon as the camera is initialised by Vuforia.

I have tried both Mono 2.x and IL2CPP both cause the same issue.

I have also set the Optimization modes to FAST and FASTEST / SMALLEST.

Comment: Any log output to help the problem?

Comment: @Slavic WARNING: 0:4: extension 'GL_EXT_frag_depth' is not supported
ERROR: 0:38: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_FragDepthEXT' WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/Internal-MotionVectors' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/Internal-MotionVectors' - Setting to default shader.
WARNING: 0:4: extension 'GL_EXT_frag_depth' is not supported ERROR/AR(2720) CameraDevice::getCameraCalibration(): Failed to get camera calibration because the camera is not initialized.

Comment: Add this to the question. I am not an expert in mobile development, but I'm advising you on how to help others help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the original questioner got resolved this I thought sharing this is useful.I faced the same issue working android build and crashing ios build when loading the 3D modal on the marker. I rebuilt the project after **disabling strip engine code** in `project settings`. Amazingly it worked in next debugging round.

This property is enabled as default. Unity docs has a description about stripping engine code as follows;

*"If this is enabled, unused modules and classes of the Unity Engine codebase will be removed in IL2CPP builds. This will result in smaller binary size. It is recommended to use this setting; however, you may want to disable it if you suspect this causes issues with your project."*